# Remote method, query and loop over relation data

Tags: node.js, loopbackjs

I have a model, **Bill**, that *hasMany* **Orders**.

If I write a remote method in Bill, how can I query a bill and loop over it's orders?

**bill.json**

```json
{
  "name": "bill",
  ...
  "relations": {
    "orders": {
      "type": "hasMany",
      "model": "order",
      "foreignKey": "orderId"
    }
}
```

**bill.js**

```js
Bill.doLoop = async function(id, body, callback) {
  let bill = await Bill.findById(id, {include: ['orders']})

  for (let order of bill.orders) {
    console.log(order);
  }
}
```

If I do this I get the following error:

> Unhandled error for request POST /api/bills/1/doLoop : TypeError: bill.orders[Symbol.iterator] is not a function

If I convert bill to a JSON string and back it is possible to access the orders, but that feels insanely dirty:

```js
let billJson = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(bill))

for (let order of billJson.orders) {
  console.log(order);
}
```

Comment: According to the error message, `bill.orders` is not [Iterable](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Iterators_and_Generators#Iterables). Have you tried: `for (let order of Object.values(billJson.orders)) { ... }` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer in Loopbacks documentation on [Include filter - Access included objects](http://loopback.io/doc/en/lb3/Include-filter.html#access-included-objects):

> In the Node.js API, call toJSON() to convert the returned model instance with related items into a plain JSON object.

Updating the code to this works:

```js
Bill.doLoop = async function(id, body, callback) {
  let bill = await Bill.findById(id, {include: ['orders']})

  for (let order of bill.toJSON().orders) {
    console.log(order);
  }
}
```